# How to get all the checkboxes that are selected by the user

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have got a list view with checkboxes.

Following is my getView method,

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        view = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            //inflate the view for each row of listview
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rating_item, null);
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            mViewHolder.mstatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingStatus);
            mViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            view.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        if (StarListHolder.getInstance().getStarOne().toString() != null) {

            String starTest = String.valueOf(listForView.get(position));
            ArrayList<String> starOne = StarListHolder.getInstance().getStarOne();
            List<String> starList = StarTest.getInstance().getStarList();
            mViewHolder.mstatus.setText(starList.get(position));
        }
        return view;
    }}
```

How can I  know the number of check boxes that are being checked by the user.

Comment: Do you just care about how many and not which are checked?

Comment: i care about which are checked

Comment: Try this... http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html

Comment: you can use isChecked() method for getting to checked check box ,for it you can use position in get view method for check box of each part of list view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Guessing you'll want to do something with that data & reflect the changes on the List. Following are the steps :

> 1) Make an interface in your Adapter.

```
interface OnListFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onListFragmentInteraction(String strSelectedItemName, int intPosition);
}
```

> 2) Apply a tap listener on the entire row / check boxes inside the `onBindViewHolder` method or `getView` method depending on whether you're using a `RecyclerView` or a `BaseAdapter` respectively.

```
holder.Row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (null != mListener) {
                // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
                // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
                mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(holder. strSelectedItemName, intPosition);
            }
        }
    });
```

> 3) Implement the interface in your Activity & inform the Adapter that changes were made in List.

```
@Override
public void onListFragmentInteraction(String strSelectedItemName, int intPosition) {
    if(lsSelection == null)
        lsSelection = new ArrayList<>();
    if(lsSelection.contains(strSelectedItemName)) {
        lsSelectedAreas.remove(strSelectedItemName);
        recyclerViewAdapter.getSelection().remove(strSelectedItemName);
        recyclerViewAdapter.getSelection().put(strSelectedItemName, false);
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemChanged(intPosition);
    } else {
        lsSelectedAreas.add(strSelectedItemName);
        recyclerViewAdapter.getSelection().remove(strSelectedItemName);
        recyclerViewAdapter.getSelection().put(strSelectedItemName, true);
        recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemChanged(intPosition);
    }
}
```

This, will trigger the row to refresh. To make provisions to handle UI to reflect this user interaction, insert this condition in your `getView` or `onBindViewHolder` methods

```
//Show selected / unselected checkbox based on isSelected Value
//hmSelection is the HashMap that maintains the list of items selected in the adapter. 
    if((hmSelection.containsKey(holder.strSelectedItemName) && hmSelection.get(holder.strSelectedItemName))
            || lsSelectedList != null && lsSelectedList.contains(holder.strSelectedItemName)) {
        if(!hmSelection.containsKey(holder.strSelectedItemName))
            hmSelection.put(holder.strSelectedItemName, true);
        holder.cbCheckBox.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkedtick_checkbox);
    } else {
        if(!hmSelection.containsKey(holder.strSelectedItemName))
            hmSelection.put(holder.strSelectedItemName, false);
        holder.cbCheckBox.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_checkbox_unselected);
    }
```

Once all that is done, just return the `List<String> lsSelectedItems` to get the final selection.

Note : I used an ImageView in place of a check box and applied the tap event for the entire row since I was using custom designed checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

```
//On your Activity or fragment Class
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   



int count = listView.getAdapter().getCount();
            LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.ll1);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                ll = (LinearLayout) gridView.getChildAt(i);

                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)ll.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
                TextView tv = (TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                //  StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
                if (cb.isChecked()) {

                    Log.e("CheckBoxch", "" + cb.getTag().toString());
                    Log.e("text", "" + tv.getTag().toString());
                    stringBuilder.append(tv.getTag().toString() + ",");
                    type_of_truck_appended = stringBuilder.toString();
                    if (pwindowforTruckName.isShowing()) {
                        pwindowforTruckName.dismiss();
                    }


                }
            } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this.**

**Define this globally in your adapter.**

```
private static int checkBoxCounter = 0;

mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked && checkBoxCounter>=2){
            list.get(position).setChecked(false);
            mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);

        }else {
            if (isChecked) {
                starOne.add((Integer) mViewHolder.mCheckBox.getTag());
                checkBoxCounter++;              
            } else {
                checkBoxCounter--;
            }
            cCheckedItems.setText(checkBoxCounter); //<-- ADD THIS
            Toast.makeText(context, "there are " + checkBoxCounter + " items selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }}});
```

Hope this will help you to solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
//add a int to you adapter class
int count = 0;

//add listener to getView()
mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count--;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create a modal class
mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray();

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        view = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            //inflate the view for each row of listview
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.rating_item, null);
            mViewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            mViewHolder.mstatus = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingStatus);
            mViewHolder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            view.setTag(mViewHolder);
        } else {
            mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        if (StarListHolder.getInstance().getStarOne().toString() != null) {
mViewHolder.mCheckBox.setTag(position);
            String starTest = String.valueOf(listForView.get(position));
            ArrayList<String> starOne = StarListHolder.getInstance().getStarOne();
            List<String> starList = StarTest.getInstance().getStarList();
            mViewHolder.mstatus.setText(starList.get(position));

            mViewHolder.mstatus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckchangeListener(data,mCheckBox));
        }
        return view;
    }

    //get all checked items by calling this method

    public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems() {
        ArrayList<String> mTempArry = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listForView.size(); i++) {
            if (mSparseBooleanArray.get(i)) {

                String data = listForView.get(i);

                mTempArry.add(data);
            }
        }

        return mTempArry;
    }
    class CheckchangeListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
        private int position;

        public CheckchangeListener(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            this.position= position;

        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                checkbox
                        .setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.notification_selected_checkbox);

            } else {
                checkbox
                        .setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.notification_checkbox);

            }
            buttonView.setChecked(isChecked);

            mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);

        }
    }
    }
```